# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'startswith' when using pandas.Series.apply() and Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, series, attributeerror

I am trying to use `BeautifulSoup` to retrieve the text of a certain element within markup strings that are stored throughout one column of a `pd.DataFrame`.

#### pd.DataFrame.info()

```bash
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 55778 entries, 0 to html
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   html    55778 non-null  object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 2.9+ MB
```

#### Code

```py
import bs4
import pandas as pd

def get_location_text(markup: str) -> str:
    selector = ".column-sm-2" # "div > ul > li"
    location = bs4.BeautifulSoup(markup, "lxml").select_one(selector)
    location_text = location.get_text(strip=True)
    return location_text

df_locations["text"] = df_locations["html"].apply(get_location_text)
```

#### Error Message

```bash
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/bl/b9g4bbkj381ghzzvws3tmcgm0000gn/T/ipykernel_50020/1441714440.py in <module>
----> 1 df_locations["text"] = df_locations["html"].apply(get_location_text)

~/bert2bert/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwargs)
   4355         dtype: float64
   4356         """
-> 4357         return SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs).apply()
   4358 
   4359     def _reduce(

~/bert2bert/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply(self)
   1041             return self.apply_str()
   1042 
-> 1043         return self.apply_standard()
   1044 
   1045     def agg(self):

~/bert2bert/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_standard(self)
   1099                     values,
   1100                     f,  # type: ignore[arg-type]
-> 1101                     convert=self.convert_dtype,
   1102                 )
   1103 

~/bert2bert/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

/var/folders/bl/b9g4bbkj381ghzzvws3tmcgm0000gn/T/ipykernel_50020/222721594.py in get_location_text(markup)
      1 def get_location_text(markup: str) -> str:
      2     selector = ".colcount-sm-2" # "div > ul > li"
----> 3     location = bs4.BeautifulSoup(markup, "lxml").select_one(selector)
      4     location_text = location.get_text(strip=True)
      5     return location_text

~/bert2bert/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py in __init__(self, markup, features, builder, parse_only, from_encoding, exclude_encodings, element_classes, **kwargs)
    327          self.contains_replacement_characters) in (
    328              self.builder.prepare_markup(
--> 329                  markup, from_encoding, exclude_encodings=exclude_encodings)):
    330             self.reset()
    331             self.builder.initialize_soup(self)

~/bert2bert/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/builder/_lxml.py in prepare_markup(self, markup, user_specified_encoding, exclude_encodings, document_declared_encoding)
    180             # We're in HTML mode, so if we're given XML, that's worth
    181             # noting.
--> 182             DetectsXMLParsedAsHTML.warn_if_markup_looks_like_xml(markup)
    183         else:
    184             self.processing_instruction_class = XMLProcessingInstruction

~/bert2bert/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/builder/__init__.py in warn_if_markup_looks_like_xml(cls, markup)
    533 
    534         if (markup is not None
--> 535             and markup.startswith(prefix)
    536             and not looks_like_html.search(markup[:500])
    537         ):

~/bert2bert/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5485         ):
   5486             return self[name]
-> 5487         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5488 
   5489     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

#### In the comment section requested debugging output

```py
df_locations["html"].describe()
```

```bash
count                                                 55778
unique                                                17077
top       <section class="mfp-hide modal-dialog modal-co...
freq                                                   3709
Name: html, dtype: object
```

```py
df_locations["html"].head(2)
```

```bash
0    <section class="mfp-hide modal-dialog modal-co...
4    <section class="mfp-hide modal-dialog modal-co...
Name: html, dtype: object
```

```py
type(df_locations["html"].iloc[0])
```

```bash
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: Can you print `df_locations['html']`?

Comment: Yes. I added the terminal output to the original question.

Comment: Can you print `type(df_locations["html"].iloc[0])`

Comment: I have appended the terminal output for ```type(df_locations["html"].iloc[0])``` to the original question.

Comment: Check your input HTML. The error tells your given input HTML looks more like XML.

Comment: Somehow apply is passing a series by the looks of it. If throw a try/expect:breakpoint() in your function. When it breaks show us what you get as output for `markup`